# Hyperlinks in thunderbird don't work

Tags: thunderbird

I recently upgraded from 12.04 to 13.10 and links in Thunderbird don't work, i.e. don't launch or open in Firefox. I have double checked that Firefox is still the default browser:

```
>> sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/x-www-browser).
Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------  
  0         /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
* 1         /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode
  2         /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
```

I have checked it is not an add-on by running Thunderbird in safe-mode. In the config editor of Thunderbird I have checked that 'network.protocol-handler.external-default' is set to 'true'. I have also added 'network.protocol-handler.app.http' to the config (linking to /usr/bin/firefox) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember I was having that issue, too.

The first thing I did was try to unset the value `network.protocol-handler.app.http` to let Thunderbird prompt me for the application. I don't remember if that worked or not.

I do remember that I eventually just created a new thunderbird profile (on the command line enter `thunderbird -P` to enter the profile prompt...pretty basic from there) and copied my settings from the first profile over to my second. Problem solved. ☺

Comment: Creating a new thunderbird profile worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading my system. Instead of creating a new profile, first tried to go to *Preferences --> Advanced --> Config editor* and set

```
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http;true
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.https;true
```

This didn't help, so I then went and moved `mimeTypes.rdf` from my profile directory. I restarted Thunderbird, and now it asked which application I would like to use to open URLs.

Just letting TB to recreate `mimeTypes.rdf` would have probably been enough, since my default browser was set up correctly. The old `mimeTypes.rdf` had settings from old environment, which obviously weren't working anymore.